# AHK! Can't get "Ctrl+Q then K" Input to work (Shortcut in Q-Dir tool)

Tags: autohotkey

Background:

So I use the Explorer tool [Q-Dir](http://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Freeware/Q-Dir) (link to homepage).

In Q-Dir you can bookmark folder you want to access regularly.
You can shortcut to those bookmarks by pressing Ctrl + Q. This opens a jumplist of your bookmarked folders.

So I want to open my projects folder which is named "Kundenprojekte" (customer projects).
Pressing "K" while said jumplist is open, opens this folder in the current tab.

So my problem occurs here:

This whole process is what I want to map with AHK to let's say WinKey + B.

This is my code so far:

```
#b:: 
qdirId := WinExist("Q-Dir 5.98.9") ; I don't know if this works I got some 
                                   ; inspiration by another AHK script
if (qdirId = 0) {
    MsgBox Q-Dir ist nicht geöffnet. ; Q-Dir is not open.
IfWinExist, "Q-Dir 5.98.9"
{
    WinActivate, "Q-Dir 5.98.9" ;I know this doesn't work plz help
    SetKeyDelay 10,1000
    Send, ^{Q}
    SetKeyDelay, 10
    Send {K}
    return
} 
}
return
```

Yes , so far there is no "else" to IfWinExist. And I don't think there will be because I would need to run Q-Dir as administrator (due to UAC preventing writing operation to my C: drive) But that is of no concern (because I usually start Q-Dir as my first programm after booting).

The main issue  I have is getting "send Control + Q" then "K" to work.

I got it to send "K" but not once was "Ctrl + Q" recognized.

Any idea what I do wrong?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2 ;  The window's title should contain "Q-Dir 5.98.9"

#b:: 
qdirId := WinExist("Q-Dir 5.98.9")
if (qdirId = 0) 
{
    MsgBox Q-Dir ist nicht geöffnet. ; Q-Dir is not open.
        return       ; stops code from going any further, to the lines below
} 
; otherwise:
WinActivate, Q-Dir 5.98.9
WinWaitActive, Q-Dir 5.98.9  ; important
SetKeyDelay 10,1000
Send, ^{Q}
; Try  also:
; Send, {CTRLDOWN}q{CTRLUP}
; SendEvent {CTRL DOWN}{q DOWN}{CTRL UP}{q Up}
SetKeyDelay, 10
Send {K}
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTitleMatchMode.htm

Comment: Hey, I just tested this. Getting Q-Dir from inactive to active mode works now. But opening the jumplist however still does not. I tested pressing WinKey + B in a text field too to see it only printin "E" or whatever the second Send is set to.

Comment: I got it to work with `SendEvent {CTRL DOWN}{q DOWN}{CTRL UP}{q Up}  
Sleep, 10` .
You really helped me dude! Thanks a lot :)